# boost::lexical_cast<int> ("-138.8468953457983248") Throws exception

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, casting

I am trying to cast this number into an integer,. But I get thrown a bad_cast exception. Im not sure whats going on.

Comment: Why do you need to cast it? It is already an `int`.

Comment: Mistake, It is a string.

Comment: @user758114: Please, only ever copy-and-paste code into Stack Overflow.  Never re-type anything.

Comment: Show your code please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the value

```
-138.8468953457983248
```

Is not an integer.

You need to convert that to a floating point value.

```
    int a = static_cast<double>("-138.21341535");
                 //     ^^^^^^   Cast to double
 // ^^^  You can assign double to an int
```

Lexical cast will try and use all the characters in the string. If there are any left over it is a bad cast. When you try and convert the above to an integer it reads "-138" but leaves ".21341535" in the cast buffer which generates an exception.

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Try\n";
    try
    {
        std::cout << boost::lexical_cast<int>("-138.8468953457983248") << "\n";
    }
    catch(boost::bad_lexical_cast const& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "Done\n";
    std::cout << "Try\n";
    try
    {
        std::cout << boost::lexical_cast<double>("-138.8468953457983248") << "\n";
    }
    catch(boost::bad_lexical_cast const& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "Done\n";
}
```

This :

```
> g++ lc.cpp
> ./a.out 
Try
Error: bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target
Done
Try
-138.847
Done
```

Comment: Are you saying -138.8468953457983248 is too long ? I just want the value -138 in the result.

Comment: @user758114: **No**. I am saying it is not an integer. lexical cast uses the `operator>>` to read the string. When it hits `.` that is not an integer and it stops reading. boost lexical_cast will throw if there is anything left in the buffer. Because the above is not an integer there is stuff left in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

`boost::lexical_cast<int>` expects a string/character stream argument.
For your requirement, you can use a static cast.

```
int a = static_cast<int>(-138.21341535);
```